# How to intialize std::map of vectors of vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, vector, c++17

I am working on pretty complex program and I need to initialize std::map variable of type `std::map<int, std::vector<std::vector<std::array<std::byte, 2>>>>` as const variable to do some comparison later. I tried to do it like this:

```cpp
const std::vector<std::vector<std::array<std::byte, 2>>>
        boundaries_length_one = {{{std::byte('\x00'), std::byte('\x7f')}}};
const std::vector<std::vector<std::array<std::byte, 2>>>
        boundaries_length_two = {{{std::byte('\xc2'), std::byte('\xdf')}, {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')}}};
const std::vector<std::vector<std::array<std::byte, 2>>> boundaries_length_three = {
        {{std::byte('\xe0'), nullptr}, {std::byte('\xa0'), std::byte('\xbf')}, {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')}},
        {{std::byte('\xe1'), std::byte('\xec')}, {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')},
         {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')}},
        {{std::byte('\xe0'), nullptr}, {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\x9f')}, {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')}},
        {{std::byte('\xee'), std::byte('\xef')}, {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')},
         {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')}}
};
const std::vector<std::vector<std::array<std::byte, 2>>> boundaries_length_four = {
        {{std::byte('\xf0'), nullptr}, {std::byte('\x90'), std::byte('\xbf')}, {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')},
         {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')}},
        {{std::byte('\xf1'), std::byte('\xf3')}, {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')},
         {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')}, {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')}},
        {{std::byte('\xf4'), nullptr}, {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\x8f')}, {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')},
         {std::byte('\x80'), std::byte('\xbf')}}
};
std::map<int, const std::vector<std::vector<std::array<std::byte, 2>>>> boundaries = {
        {1, boundaries_length_one},
        {2, boundaries_length_two},
        {3, boundaries_length_three},
        {4, boundaries_length_four}};
```

The code above is located in separate namepace.
And unfortunately, I got this error:

```
In file included from /Users/denisivanenko/CLionProjects/UnicodeProcessorCpp/utf8.cpp:5:
/Users/denisivanenko/CLionProjects/UnicodeProcessorCpp/utf8.h:63:58: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'const std::vector<std::vector<std::array<std::byte, 2> > >'
const std::vector<std::vector<std::array<std::byte, 2>>> boundaries_length_three = {
                                                         ^                         ~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:528:9: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_InputIterator'
        vector(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, const allocator_type& __a,
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:542:9: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_ForwardIterator'
        vector(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, const allocator_type& __a,
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:520:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 4 were provided
        vector(_InputIterator __first,
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:535:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 4 were provided
        vector(_ForwardIterator __first,
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:518:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 4 were provided
    vector(size_type __n, const value_type& __x, const allocator_type& __a);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:515:14: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 4 were provided
    explicit vector(size_type __n, const allocator_type& __a);
             ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:517:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 4 were provided
    vector(size_type __n, const value_type& __x);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:558:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 4 were provided
    vector(const vector& __x, const allocator_type& __a);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:567:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 4 were provided
    vector(initializer_list<value_type> __il, const allocator_type& __a);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:578:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 4 were provided
    vector(vector&& __x, const allocator_type& __a);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:501:40: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__a', but 4 arguments were provided
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY explicit vector(const allocator_type& __a)
                                       ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:513:14: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__n', but 4 arguments were provided
    explicit vector(size_type __n);
             ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:557:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__x', but 4 arguments were provided
    vector(const vector& __x);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:564:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__il', but 4 arguments were provided
    vector(initializer_list<value_type> __il);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:570:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__x', but 4 arguments were provided
    vector(vector&& __x)
    ^
```

Error was a bit longer, but note message everywhere is almost the same, only number of elements needed and provided differ.

Can anyone help me initialize such a complex structure? I use C++17, clang 11.0.3 and CMake 3.17.2.

Comment: Weird, your code compiles fine with gcc (even with -pedantic). Which is correct?

Comment: You are using `nullptr` where a `std::byte` is expected. `nullptr` is for pointers, it's not convertible to `std::byte`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks a lot, the problem was only in `nullptr`\`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it. The prolem was in `nullptr``s I used in place of std::byte.